# Show/hide div if "other" radio OR checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I realize this is not terribly different from a lot of other questions that have been asked, but it's the little differences that's making it tricky for me.

Basically, I want to show or hide the text input to specify the "other" option if "other" is checked.

My approach seems to work fine for the checkboxes. But the the other text input won't hide when you uncheck the other radio button. I know the nature of radios is a little different, but I'm not sure how to accommodate this.

Here's the code, and I've also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQsJy/2) where you can see it in action. Thanks for your help!

### HTML

```
<fieldset>
<h1>Pick One</h1>
<p><label><input value="1" type="radio" name="options"> Chicken</label></p>
<p><label><input value="2" type="radio" name="options"> Beef</label></p>
<p><label><input value="3" type="radio" name="options"> Fish</label></p>
<p><label><input value="4" type="radio" name="options" class="other"> Other</label></p>
<p class="specify-other"><label>Please specify: <input name="options-other"></label></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<h1>Pick Several</h1>
<p><label><input value="1" type="checkbox" name="food"> Rice</label></p>
<p><label><input value="2" type="checkbox" name="food"> Beans</label></p>
<p><label><input value="3" type="checkbox" name="food"> Potatoes</label></p>
<p><label><input value="4" type="checkbox" name="food" class="other"> Other</label></p>
<p class="specify-other"><label>Please specify: <input name="options-other"></label></p>
</fieldset>
```

### jQuery

```
$('.other').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').children(".specify-other").show('fast');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').children(".specify-other").hide('fast');
    }
});
```

### CSS

```
.specify-other {display: none;}
```

Comment: You can change `$(this).is(':checked')` to `this.checked` - it's **much** more efficient, and semantically identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my approach: working on the whole radio "group":

```
$('input[name=options]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('other')) {
      $(this).parents('fieldset').children(".specify-other").show('fast');
    } else {
      $(this).parents('fieldset').children(".specify-other").hide('fast');
    }
})
```

Comment: I made one tweak: Changing my selector to `'input:radio, input:checkbox'`. This seems to do it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, my tweak doesn't play nice with the checkbox. It sort of reverses my original problem! I think I may have to combine the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

ok 
whenever you click on radio button it always checked, its not like checkbox to check or uncheck on click.

you have check for radio button with some condition as group of all radio button so check with value that if value=4 is checked then show other wish hide