# Show/hide div if “other” radio OR checkbox is checked with Formtastic

Tags: formtastic

This is a lot like other questions that have been asked. I know how to do this with HTML/Javascript, but my question specific to Formtastic.

(Here is a link to almost the same exact question, except all I need is to figure out how to get Formtastic to emit the HTML similar to the example here: [Show/hide div if "other" radio OR checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125738/show-hide-div-if-other-radio-or-checkbox-is-checked))

Often you'll have a list of radio buttons:

- Choice 1
- Choice 2
- Choice 3

Well, that is all fine and dandy, and Formtastic handles it with ease. But then what happens when I want this:

- Choice 1
- Choice 2
- Choice 3
- Other:         [ text input here]

The text input should be greyed until I click "Other." If I choose "Other" I need the user to type in what it is. (And the same argument would apply with checkboxes as well.)

I realize the interactivity is Javascript, and not Formtastic's job as far as that goes. What I'm talking about is the actual markup.

Is there a way to make Formtastic emit this?

Answer (score 0):

Formtastic doesn't have anything out-of-the-box for this, mostly because I'm not aware of an established pattern for how the params should look when posting the form data. Without a convention and good support on the model end, it feels like we'd only be half-baking something that might work for some people.

The good news is you can half-bake your own solution with a custom input. Instead of `:as => :select` do `:as => :select_with_other`, and then start building up your own `SelectWithOtherInput` in `app/inputs/select_with_other_input.rb`:

`class SelectWithOtherInput < Formtastic::Inputs::SelectInput
end`

You'll want to have a look in the source code for SelectInput and the modules it includes to get a feel for what you'll need to override to get what you want, but this is the only way to do it at this time.

If you can establish a nice pattern for this, I'd be happy to look at a patch.